# AWK: Passing shell variables to awk

Tags: shell-script, awk

I am trying to pass a **variable** number of arguments from the shell script to a pattern recognition subset of a table. Here is my attempt so far:

The file 'infile':

```
    ID,GROUP
    1,GROUP2    
    2,GROUP2    
    3,GROUP4    
    4,GROUP4    
    5,GROUP5    
    6,GROUP5    
    7,GROUP23   
    8,GROUP23   
    9,GROUP23
```

The file subset.sh:

```
    #!/bin/sh
    rm -f outfile_$week

    week = $1
    shift

    for TOKEN in "$@"
    do

    echo "adding records for" $TOKEN

    awk -F "," -v group = $TOKEN '{ if(FNR > 2 && $2 ~/group/){print $0} }' infile >> outfile_$week
    done
```

I have also tried group = "$TOKEN", "group = $TOKEN" and then both with single quotes. I am submitting like this:

```
    sh subset.sh 061314 GROUP2 GROUP23
```

The error I get is an astoundingly uninformative

```
    Usage: awk [-F fs][-v Assignment][-f Progfile|Program][Assignment|File] ...
```

Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

EDIT:
I tried running

```
    awk -F "," -v group ="GROUP1" '{ if(FNR > 2 && $2 ~/group/){print $0} }' infile
```

to no avail... (same error as above) anyone know of any reason this might happen?

Comment: what's the `rm -f infile` doing inside `subset.sh`?

Comment: Not related to your actual question, but afaik `$2 ~/group/` will do a regex match against _literal_ string `group`. To match against the _variable_ you need `$2 ~ group`. In fact the whole expression could be much simpler `'FNR > 2 && $2 ~ group'` since `print $0` is the default action if the test evaluates `true`.

Comment: @1_CR that's a typo, I was changing the names for simplicity.

Comment: You need to not put any spaces around the `=`. That's what is wrong with everything you have tried. Gnouc's answer is the correct way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want:

```
awk -F, '
  BEGIN {
    for (i = 1; i < ARGC; i++) group[ARGV[i]]
    ARGC=0
  }
  NR >= 2 && $2 in group' "$@" < infile
```

Or if you really want to consider the arguments as regexps to match against the second column:

```
awk -F, '
  BEGIN {
    for (i = 1; i < ARGC; i++) group[ARGV[i]]
    ARGC=0
  }
  NR >= 2 {
    for (i in group) if ($2 ~ i) {print; next}
  }' "$@" < infile
```

Answer (score 4):

You should write:

```
-v group="$TOKEN"
```

instead of `-v group = $TOKEN`, which causes syntax error in `awk`.

Comment: If you write `-v "group = $TOKEN"`, you may see this error: `awk: fatal: 'foo ' is not a legal variable name`

Answer (score 2):

Your immediate problem is the spaces around the equal sign. The argument to the `-v` option should be an assignment. Awk sees an argument to `-v`, followed by a script (`=`), followed by file names (the value of `TOKEN`, your script, and your file names).

You made a similar error in the shell script further up: `week = $1` should be `week="$1"`.

By the way, [always put double quotes around command substitutions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters). For example, if `TOKEN` is `*`, it would be replaced by the list of files in the current directory.

```
awk -v "group=$TOKEN"
```

This doesn't set `group` to the value of `TOKEN`, though, because awk treats the right-hand side of the assignment as a literal in awk syntax. For example, if the value of `TOKEN` is the 7-character string `foo\bar`, then the awk variable `group` is set to the 6-character string `foo␈ar` where `␈` is a backspace character (byte value 8).

The straightforward way to pass a variable to an awk script is to export it to the environment, and use it via the `ENVIRON` array.

In addition, you aren't using the variable `group` anywhere in the awk script. The regexp `/group/` matches any string containing the 5-character string `group`. If you want to check whether the field is exactly the value of `group` (so that e.g. if the value of `TOKEN` is `GROUP2` then a field containing `GROUP24` won't be matched), use the equality operator `==`.

```
  export TOKEN
  awk -F "," '{ if (FNR > 2 && $2 == ENVIRON["TOKEN"]){print $0} }' infile >> outfile_$week
```

Here's the whole script, simplified a little further to use awk's condition-action syntax (where the action is omitted here since `print $0` is the default) and to avoid opening the output file every time:

```
#!/bin/sh
week="$1"
shift
for TOKEN in "$@"
do
  echo "adding records for" $TOKEN
  awk -F "," 'FNR > 2 && $2 == ENVIRON["TOKEN"]' infile 
done >"outfile_$week"
```

See [Stéphane Chazelas's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/137027) for a more advanced way to use awk that doesn't require processing the input file multiple times.